# Function to check whether entire list is prime numbers

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, primes

I have a prime function which accepts a list of numbers and checks if all of the numbers in the list are prime.

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt
def primes(lista):
    return all(True if n == 2 else bool(all(n % x for x in list(range(3, int(sqrt(n)+1), 2))+ [2])) for n in lista)
```

Can I make this code more readable without making the actual function slower?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372)?

Comment: To answer this well we really need to know the intended usage: will `lista` be small or large, will its elements be small or large, and if the answers are respectively small and large, will the elements be contained in a small range?

Comment: Also, does `lista` contain multiple elements?

Comment: `lista` can contain 1 or more elements, and lista will usually be large, about 100 - 200 elements in `lista`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few obvious improvements, which either make it more readable or even faster:

- `True if n == 2 else ...` is equivalent to `n == 2 or ...`
- `bool(all(...))` is the same as `all()`
- You could pull out the special case of `2` in `all(n % x for x in list(range(3, int(sqrt(n)+1), 2))+ [2])` by doing `(n % 2 and all(n % x for x in range(3, int(sqrt(n)+1), 2)))`. This has the advantage that the `range` does not get consumed into a list which makes this stop generating values as soon as a value is found not to be prime.

This gives:

```
from math import sqrt

def primes(lista):
    return all(n == 2 or (n % 2 and all(n % x for x in range(3, int(sqrt(n)+1), 2))) for n in lista)
```

But if you really want to make it more readable, you should factor out the prime check into another function:

```
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(n):
    """Check if `n` is prime.

    Uses exhaustive search to look for factors up to sqrt(n) + 1.
    """
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    return all(n % x for x in range(3, int(sqrt(n) + 1), 2))


def all_primes(lista):
    """Check if all numbers in `lista` are primes."""
    return all(is_prime(n) for n in lista)
```

Another alternative is to compute a set of primes once and then just check if all of them are in this set:

```
primes_set = set(prime_sieve(100000))

def all_primes_set(lista):
    lista_set = set(lista)
    return len(primes_set & lista_set) == len(lista_set)
```

On my machine all of these are faster than your original function:

```
primes_list = list(prime_sieve(100000))

%timeit primes_op(primes_list)
77.3 ms ± 373 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit primes(primes_list)
67.8 ms ± 706 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit all_primes(primes_list)
70.9 ms ± 235 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit all_primes_set(primes_list)
823 µs ± 9.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So if you know what the largest number is which you need to check, checking against a `set` that is computed only once is the fastest.

Comment: I apologize for intrude in here, but what if the list of primes to check has more than 100000 numbers, does it return false? Just curious and don't know Python. **EDIT** Nevermind, failed to read the retrun condition.

Comment: I never understand why people special-case 2 when checking for primality. Why 2? Who not 3? Why not 31? There’s absolutely nothing special about 2 as a prime (apart from being the first, but by induction then we should also special case 3, after checking for 2. And then 5, after checking for 3. … aaand we’ve reinvented the sieve.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph it is the only even prime, so you can go in steps of 2 afterwards

Comment: @Graipher And after checking for 3 we can go up in steps of 3 (and check the n and n+1). Again, this is just the beginning of the sieve.

Comment: @auhmaan I just chose a number that is probably larger than the largest number in `lista`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But you run into the law of diminishing returns. With 2 you get to eliminate half, for 3 only another sixth and so on...

Answer (score 5):

for each number in `lista`, you iterate over the `range(3, int(sqrt(n)+1), 2)`. You even unnecessarily instantiate this range to a `list`.

You have 2 alternatives.

1. You test each element in `lista` with a faster prime tester
2. You generate all primes to `max(lista)`, and then check whether all elements from `lista` are in those primes

Which of the 2 options is better depends on `lista`. If there are a lot, smaller elements, the 2nd method is faster, for a few, larger elements, method 1 will be better.

I will not get into details on which method to generate all the primes to `max(lista)`, or the prime check. Here you can choose the algorithm most suited for your need. There are a lot alternative on the web and SO.

## method 1

This is basically what you did, but with an inline, slow check for primes

```
def isprime(x):
    pass # choose your test

def test_primes(lista):
    return all(isprime(x) for x in lista)
```

This can be rewritten with `map`

```
def test_primes(lista):
    return all(map(isprime, lista))
```

Whichever of these 2 is best depends mainly on preference

## method 2:

```
def get_primes_to(x):
    pass

def test_primes(lista):
    max_a = max(lista)
    primes = set(get_primes_to(max_a))
    return all(i in primes for i in lista)
```

### method 2b

Checking whether all elements of `lista` are primes can also be done with [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)

```
def test_primes(lista):
    max_a = max(lista)
    primes = set(get_primes_to(max_a))
    return set(lista) <= primes
```

Comment: Method 2b requires no intermediary set object for `lista` because `set.issuperset()` accepts arbitrary iterables: `primes.issuperset(lista)`. The implemented algorithm should be similar to the generator expression in method 2a.